# Android Can hint remain in editText during user input?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to keep the hint in an edittext to make an editable block of preset text? If so, how would one go about doing so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310415/android-edittext-remain-hint-visible-and-right-sided

Comment: Instead of `android:hint="asdf"` use `android:text="asdf"` in your xml layout.